# $\limsup A_{n} $ and $\liminf A_{n} $ calculations.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I am reading  measure  theoritic  probability with self study mode from online materials. In limsup  and liminf of  sequence  of sets I am confused about how to tackle this question.

> Given $\Omega$ is a nonempty set and $A,B \subseteq\Omega$ with $A \neq B$.
>
> Define,
> $A_{n} = \begin{cases}
>           A & \text{if n is odd}\\
>           B &\text{if n is even}
>           \end{cases}$.
>
> How to find $\limsup A_{n}$ and $\liminf A_{n}$.

My approach is to use the formal definition which  uses the union and intersection  of sets.Very much depressed from that. How should  I solve this.
Any explanatory proof is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: In general, \begin{align*}\limsup A_n&=\{\omega\in\Omega:\omega\in A_n\text{ infinitely often}\}\\\liminf A_n&=\{\omega\in\Omega:\omega\in A_n\text{ eventually}\}.\end{align*} From this, it is not hard to obtain that, with $A_n$ given as in OP, $$\limsup A_n=A\cup B, \qquad \liminf A_n=A\cap B.$$

Answer (score 1):

No depression is required.
$$ \liminf A_n = \bigcup _{k=1}^\infty \bigcap _{n\geqslant k}A_n \overset{?}= A\cap B $$
For $\subseteq$ take any $k\in\mathbb N$ and note that $\omega\in \bigcap _{n\geqslant k}A_n$ implies $\omega \in A\cap B$. Conversely, $\omega\in A$ means that $\omega \in A_m$ for all odd $m\in\mathbb N$. So, assuming $\omega\in A\cap B$, there must exist $k\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$ \forall n\left ( n\geqslant k \Rightarrow \omega \in A_n \right ). $$
The argument for the upper limit works out similarly.